# $ git status On branch master Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 38 and 9 different commits each, respectively

Tags: git, github

I have problem with git.
After command git status on server I see:

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 38 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
    new file:   wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp-child/images/descriptionStat.svg
    new file:   wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp-child/images/statistics.svg
    new file:   wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp-child/images/statistics_first.svg
    new file:   wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp-child/images/statistics_last.svg
    new file:   wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp-child/images/statistics_one.svg
```

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
**All project files .......**

How to solve this problem?I recently work with Git. Thank you all very much

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to learn how git works, your best option is to find some tutorials that tells you and go through those. The messages from git indicate that you have made 9 commits locally, that you haven't pushed yet. Since you started that, someone else has already pushed 38 commits to the server, which you don't have. This means your local master and the remote master diverges. Your best option, probably, is to merge those two diverging branches using `git pull`. However, at the same time, you have uncommitted local changes. You should probably commit those first.

Comment: The reason I said you should find some tutorials is that this is by no means an exceptional situation. This might be a regular situation on your team, so you need to learn how to cope with it, because it's highly likely it will keep happening, regularly and often. Your manager might be able to help with providing access to training materials and courses, you should talk to him/her and to your coworkers, in order to obtain some training on git.

Comment: Hi, after commands git pull I see new error:  

$ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Comment: Yes, you need to commit your uncommitted changes before you can pull.